# jBPM how to link a certain task to a java function and how to output a data?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I'm using jBPM with eclipse to test this workflow engine with java, I've read the documentation but I don't how to link a task to function ? and how to configure the output of a task to the output of this function?

For example I have a task SaveMail it needs to send to the next task an html file

Answer (score 1):

To send data/info from SaveMail task to next task you can use process variable or global variable. In SaveMail under output variable mapping, map task variable to process variable and then use it in next task.